# How to send local push notifications in a time interval

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uikit

Recently, I started working with iOS development, and I'm currently working on adding new functionality to an existing app. For the current feature, I need to schedule push notifications in a pre-defined time interval, for a specific number of times; let's say between 8:00 and 20:00, every ~2 hours. In addition, I'd like to define custom behaviour when the notification is tapped (open a specific view).

I'm currently able to use the existing notification service to send text based push notifications on demand, but I'm not yet able to define this custom interval/behaviour

**What is the best way to handle this scenario?**

```
private func sendLocalNotification() {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Title"
    content.body  = "Body"
    
    // defining a trigger for custom behaviour
    // var trigger: UNNotificationTrigger?
        
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: TestNotification.identifier, content: content, trigger: .none)
    userNotificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Comment: did you read this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app
if yes, what didn't work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule Local Notification in iOS / irregular time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236606/schedule-local-notification-in-ios-irregular-time-interval)

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotificationalloc] init]; 
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7200];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

try this